# Handling new window in Internet Explorer using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, download

I am using selenium webdriver to automate a scenario where in clicking on a download image opens a new window. This new window will have the "Save As" dialog box.

As soon as I click on the image, new window opens up but is closed immediately without displaying the "Save as" Dialog box.

My scenario is to make sure the file is present and read the file name by clicking on the save as button.

My code:

```
WebElement e1= driver.findElement(By.id("id of image"));
e1.click(); 
Set<String> set = driver.getWindowHandles();
List<String> handles = new ArrayList<String>(set);
driver.switchTo().window(handles.get(1)); // switch to file download dialog box
```

Comment: What happens when you use the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my exp, Seleniun file download test is a pain to automation engineer. Instead of doing step-by-step download, we could use HttpURLConnection, Apache HttpComponents (or maybe just a file get through URL) for the link specified and assert a 200 OK response.

For more information, you can refer to following link for tools to handle this case

https://github.com/Ardesco/Ebselen/blob/master/ebselen-core/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/ebselen/customhandlers/FileDownloader.java

http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/